# Challenging a close-question decision

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I was in the process of answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034533/api-jena-get-values-of-data-properties) when it got closed underneath me as an exact dup. However, the OP has provided more information this go around, so either it's not an *exact* dup, or, perhaps better, the other question should be closed and this one left open for the dialogue to complete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since neither question is answered yet, I went ahead and opened that one back up and closed [the (less detailed) original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985079/fill-textfields-with-values-of-datatypeproperties-regarding-an-instance-of-perso) as a duplicate.  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4):

Agree. Question closing as an "exact" dup can be sometimes pretty annoying, e.g.

1. when the new question is better formulated, brings new facts or arguments,
2. when the answers on the old question do not cover the topic well,
3. for duplicates of old (+1y) discussions (here on meta), the newly added posts to old discussions don't stand a chance in a lot of highly upvoted ones - so newly put arguments don't stand chance either. New views need new discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Posting here, you can send the masses back to reconsider and vote to re-open the question.

The [more recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034533/api-jena-get-values-of-data-propertie) question appears to be a newer version of this individual's code.  Both questions begin with the exact same paragraph.  [The older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985079) is here for comparison.

Comment: You can, indeed, send the masses back to reconsider by posting on Meta. But this is risky. If people disagree with your challenge, you'll often find the referenced question downvoted into oblivion and deleted altogether!